# вылетает android приложение при подключении к firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, клиент-сервер

Учусь делать клиент-серверное приложение, при написании следующих строчек приложение вылетает. когда убираю эти строчки, приложение запускается. не могу найти проблему. буду благодарен за помощь

````
 private static final int SIGN_IN_CODE = 1;
    private RelativeLayout activity_main;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        activity_main = findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

        //the user hasn't signed up yet
        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null)
            startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().build(), SIGN_IN_CODE);
        else
            Snackbar.make(activity_main, "You're already signed up", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show(); ```
````

Comment: Проверьте логи в LogCat

Comment: 2021-03-11 15:27:54.168 2837-2866/? E/hypnusd: submit dspfreq failed(Unknown error 524)
2021-03-11 15:27:54.210 641-691/? E/UxUtility: notifyAppState error = NULL
2021-03-11 15:27:56.880 1451-3465/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).

вот такие логи

Comment: Логи следует добавить в вопрос через редактирование. Кроме того, логи ошибки как правило много длиннее того, что Вы указали в комменте. Проверьте, выставлен ли в логах фильтр только Вашего приложения? Ощущение, что это какой-то системный лог. Нужный лог появится при вылете приложения.

Answer (score 0):

Вы зачем-то используете `Snackbar.make` , хотя это нигде не определено. Используйте для показа сообщения `Toast`

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/582390)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy ответом является, ибо указывает на ошибку

Comment: Как использование [Snackbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/snackbar/Snackbar) приводит к ошибке?